Is it possible to Misty Step to a location visible through a Familiar, outside of initiative?
The shared senses of Find Familiar has been changed to a Bonus Action in the 2024 PHB.

as a Bonus Action, you can see through the familiar’s eyes and hear what it hears until the start of your next turn, gaining the benefits of any special senses it has.

Misty Step allows a character to teleport to an observable location.

Briefly surrounded by silvery mist, you teleport up to 30 feet to an unoccupied space you can see.

However, both actions require a Bonus Action. Since, only one Bonus Action is available per turn

You can take only one Bonus Action on your turn, so you must choose which Bonus Action to use if you have more than one available.

Both features cannot be used in the same turn, e.g. in Combat.
However, turns only exist within the context of initiative order. And, there doesn't seem to be any indication that the limitations for turns exist during normal exploration or social interaction, other than a note under Actions:

The game uses actions to govern how much you can do at one time. You can take only one action at a time. This principle is most important in combat...

But, there seems to be some ambiguity about whether or not Bonus Actions are actions. If they are actions, then they should e.g. be eligible to be Ready-ed; if they aren't actions, then the "only one action at a time" doesn't necessarily apply to them, which would make the combination of Misty Step and Find Familiar permissible.
So, it the combination permissible outside of turn order?

Are you looking at absolute raw for this? Nobody* forces constant bonus actions out of combat to see through a familiar, not even in combat most of the time.

What are the 2024 rules for simultaneous effects?  For start-of-turn effects?  If you have the familiar's senses until the start of your next turn, why can't you use misty step at the start of your next turn?  It seems like two things may be triggered by the start of your next turn: your bonus action resets, and your familiar sense drops.  Depending on how these simultaneous effects resolve, and what 'start of turn' means, this could be possible even in combat.  More citations of relevant rules are needed.

@Kirt your turn is between the start & the end. As soon as your turn starts, your familiar vision ends, before any "on your turn" events. It's only simultaneous with other start-of-turn events.

No

You can take only one action at a time.

So, one action at a time, even when not tracking turns.
And Bonus Actions say:

... let you take an additional action on your turn ... You can take a bonus action only when ... the game states that you can ...

There are two options:

It being your turn is one of the conditions that the game states is required for taking a Bonus Action. There are no turns outside of combat. So, the conditions for taking a Bonus Action of any sort are not met.
Whenever you are doing something, it's your turn. That is, there are turns happening all the time, but we only track them in combat. You can only have one Bonus Action on your turn no matter how long it is, therefore, you can't do the combination you suggest.


The text of features favors the second option, as at least some features that have no combat application have action requirements.
